# Form elements have same width but are not showing aligned

Tags: html, css

I have the following two form fields. They have the same width so they should be displayed aligned and they do so except for Google Chrome. In Google Chrome, the textarea has a little more width. Please help me out in fixing it. Thanks

```
           <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone"  style=" font-family: Verdana; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 13px;background-color: #0E0E0F; border: 1px solid #740086; width:385px;  margin-bottom:10px;" size="38" value="Phone #" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
   <textarea
    name="message"
    cols="38"
    rows="12"
    id="message"
    style="font-family:Verdana; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; background-color:#0E0E0F; border:1px solid #740086; width:38px; margin-bottom:10px;overflow:hidden;"
    onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
Message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code you posted your text area has a `width:38px;` did you mean to have `width:385px;` to match the width of the input field? you may also want to include a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: @Wex: I just did a little research on reset stylesheet. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that 38px in the style for the `textarea` element is a typo and should be 385px, otherwise you would the area as narrow on all CSS-enabled browsers. And I suspect that in the real code, there is something that causes a line break between the `input` and `textarea` elements; otherwise it is difficult to compare their widths.

The reason why the textarea is slightly wider on Chrome is that by the [browser stylesheet for WebKit-based browsers](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css), `textarea` elements have 2px padding. You can see this if you use the Inspect element tool of Chrome (via right-clicking) and view “Metrics” there.

The apparent solution is then `textarea { padding: 0; }`. But since the padding is actually useful, it might be better to set

```
textarea, input { padding: 2px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sizing the input element using the `size` attribute and using `cols` in your textarea.

You also are defining two styles: `width:385px` and `width:38px` (the inequality is probably your problem). I'm not sure which takes precidence (`size` or `cols`), but why not avoid confusion and just set equal an `width` for both elements and just remove the `size` and `row`/`col` definitions?

Comment: There are various reasons for sizing elements in HTML, including the usual CSS Caveats. Besides, `rows` and `cols` are required by HTML syntax rules.